# Wrong reference to cell in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I'm developing importer based on PHPExcel library.

This piece of code saves the cells for later usage.

```
foreach ($this->importModel->currentAttributeNames as $columnLabel => $attribute) {
    $cell = $this->_sheet->getCell($columnLabel . $row->getRowIndex());
    $this->importModel->importModelAttributes[$attribute]->setDefaultValueCell($cell);         
}
```

`$this->_sheet` contains current sheet which is valid `PHPExcel_Worksheet` object.

Saved cells contain valid `PHPExcel_Cell` object.

Later I try to use it also in `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($this->importModel->importModelAttributes as $importModelAttribute) {
    var_dump($importModelAttribute->_defaultValueCell);

    ...
}
```

`$importModelAttribute->_defaultValueCell->getValue()` returns correct value, but `getCoordinate()` returns the coordinate of first cell of the last row with data in this sheet (`A11`) while it must be `B7`.

Some other calculations are done and they depend on style of the cells (color in this case), and it also returns style from `A11` cell.

For testing and debugging purposes I also tried to clone cell objects but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell collection object in PHPExcel keeps one cell (the last referenced) as an active cell.... your `$cell` object is effectively a pointer pointing to that one active cell.

In practical terms, your call to `setDefaultValueCell($cell);` will store the cell pointer in `$defaultValueCell`, which will be pointing to the correct cell at the point where you make the call, but the next iteration will adjust that the pointer to the new `$cell` value, because tat is the new "active" cell.

You could try "cloning" using

```
$cell = clone $this->_sheet->getCell($columnLabel . $row->getRowIndex());
```

but you're probably better just storing the cell address/coordinate in `$defaultValueCell` and then using

```
foreach ($this->importModel->importModelAttributes as $importModelAttribute) {
    $cell = $this->_sheet->getCell($importModelAttribute->_defaultValueCell)
    ...
}
```

in your second loop

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I actually thought about storing coordinate and sheet number as alternative. If I call `getCell($coordinate)` again where it will be loaded from? From cache or will be processed again? In other words, how it will affect perfomance?

Comment: Another call to getCell() will reload that cell from cache (if it's cached) and reset it as the active cell... how much of a performance overhead this is will depend on the caching that you're using